# Unexpected redirection while parsing string

Tags: busybox, ash

I have a string that parses files. But when i execute it. It gives an error. Here is the code;

```
config="/tmp/files.config"
tftp $TFTP_SERVER_IP -c get "files.config" "$config"

while read line
do
    IFS='=' read -a current_line <<< "$line"
tftp $TFTP_SERVER_IP -c "${current_line[0]}" "${current_line[1]}"
done < "$config"
```

Here is the error;

```
line 6: syntax error: unexpected redirection
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe

```
tftp $TPTP_SERVER_IP -c "${line#*=}" "${line%=*}"
```

(that is — instead of the whole `while` body).

```
$ ash
$ line="asdasdsad=123123123123"
$ echo $line
asdasdsad=123123123123
$ echo ${line%=*}
asdasdsad
$ echo ${line#*=}
123123123123
$
```

Comment: `"${line%=*}"` returns empty. But first parameter is correct.